# else function in python failure

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a noob to python, and I have been having trouble with the if/else function. for some reason the "else" part is always highlighted as a syntax error, every single time I change it! this is my code:

```
    input ('password:')
    if a == 'KARM' (print ('access granted.')
        (print ('welcome to python'))
    else
        print ('nope. go away.')
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: Why did you revert the formatting change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yikes your formatting is all messed up! Give this a try:

```
a = input('password:')

if a == 'KARM':
    print('access granted.')
    print('welcome to python')

else:
    print('nope. go away.')
```

In python if and else statements end with a colon ":" and indentation matters. Also you were trying to use `a` before defining it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using colons:

```
input ('password:')
if a == 'KARM':
    (print ('access granted.')
    (print ('welcome to python'))
else:
    print ('nope. go away.')
```